# Is it possible to download a sharepoint site to HTML which can be stored on a removable media?

Tags: sharepoint-server, html, site, download

I'm working with sharepoint and have found a need to download a sharepoint site onto a removable drive such as a CD or USB. I've looked at several StackExchange pages and searched the web for a solution and all I can find is downloading documents or lists. However, it would be very benefitial if it was possible to get the whole website and be able to use it offline like a static HTML page.

With other words, it would be great if the stucture of the page was still available and usable offline with all images and documents.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think something like this is possible , however what you can get is sync any library /list to one drive for business .